# Getting bytes form nsdata apends extra junk characters

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, pointers, nsdate

I am trying to get bytes from nsdata into char* but the length of char* is more than length of nsdata and contains extra junk characters appended at the last.The code:

```
 NSData * newData=[self dataFromHexString:trimmedHex];
 NSLog(@"new data length %d",[newData length]);
 char * ciphertext=(char*)[newData bytes];
 NSLog(@"length of ciphertext %zd",strlen(ciphertext));
```

The log:

```
2013-08-02 17:02:28.175 AES[4187:11303] new data length 128
2013-08-02 17:02:28.176 AES[4187:11303] length of ciphertext 144
```

stuck with this from morning.:(

```
const char * ciphertextTemp=(const char*)[newData bytes];
char ciphertext[[newData length]+1];
for (int len=0; len<[self length];len++) {
    ciphertext[len]=ciphertextTemp[len];
}
ciphertext[[self length]]='\0';
```

Comment: I'm not into Objective-C, but could it be the `0`-terminator is mssing for the sequences of `char`s `ciphertext` is pointing to?

Comment: ya that was it :) thank you.i added the delimiter like ciphertext[[self length]]='\0'; it return the exact lenghth .thank you again.

Comment: Are you sure you may write to `ciphertext[[self length]]` as this is one byte **after** were `newData` points to.

Comment: Extra junk characters were getting appended to the cipher text cos of which my decrypted string was wrong,i did this to avoid the junk characters ,is there any harm in doing like this ?if so can you pls suggest an alternative ?

Comment: Nothing got appended. The "string" was simply missing its `0`-termination. So `strlen()` did not find the proper end, but just took the next "random" `0` it found when scanning the memory pointed to by `ciphertext` as the "string"s `0`-termination. You might like to read about how a C-"string" is represented in memory.

Comment: Ok ,but since the bytes method of nsdata class is not providing the delimiter i am providing it :ciphertext[[newData length]]='\0' so that shoudl solve it right ?

Comment: I strongly assume the memory referenced by `ciphertext[[newData length]]` does not belong to the data representation of this instance of `NSData` So writing a `0`in there writes to unallocated memory (or memory belonging to an instance of another class), which itself provokes Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: And what i meant by junk characters getting appended was my cipher text actually contained characters till the next random 0 delimeter u are talking abt.So when i run a loop on the cipher text using strlen() i get some junk characters as well which i shouldnt decrypt.

Comment: You need to somehow expand the NSData object by one 1 byte. Or create a new one of this size and then copy the original content into it. After having done so you could write the `0` in there. And again: You might like to read about how a C-"string" is represented in memory.

Comment: ok thanks will try to do that and will "read about how a C-"string" is represented in memory" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be the `0`-terminator is missing for the sequences of `char`s `ciphertext` is pointing to?

---

**Update:**

Instead of

```
for (int len=0; len<[self length];len++) {
  ciphertext[len]=ciphertextTemp[len];
}
ciphertext[[self length]]='\0';
```

you could simply do:

```
strncpy(ciphertext, ciphertextTemp, [newData length]);
ciphertext[[self length] - 1]='\0';
```

Comment: I edited the implementation(see the question),this should solve it right ?

Comment: @Suhas_United: Not exactly, as C arrays are 0-indexed. Please see my updated answer.